# Explicitly solving linear programming problems

Tags: linear-programming

Linear programming problems generically involve the use of a repeated algorithm to solve. Is there a reason they can't be solved algebraically/formulaically?

Ex:

Minimize x1 + x2 + x3....

x1, x2, x3... >= 1

Has a solution (1,1,1...) for any dimension

With a little work we can extend this to include coefficients...

Is there a way to explicitly solve any LP? What proof is there that it cannot exist? What machinery would be needed before such a thing can be done

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "explicitely". Do you think that there is a way to solve any linear system explicitely? If you would say yes, then there is also a way to solve any LP explicitely...

Comment: Like given any quadratic you can just plug it into the quadratic equation and its done... The algorithm needs to be used one time... In a single stream of calculations

Comment: Can LP's be approached the same way?